# How can I change bank statement purchase identifier inside Client card GOOGLE PLAY

Tags: revenuecat

I'm new using **REVENEU CAT** (https://www.revenuecat.com/) to integrate payments in my flutter app. I already made a test today using my own credit card to test a purchase of a in app product. Everything is nice, but the name that is appearing in my card is wrong. I suppose that the client must see another name in the app purchase, but i getting the following label:

[image]

IDK why appears YOUTUBE because the purchase wasn't made in that app. Could you help me?

I already configure my payments profile in google and the bank statement name says other name…

I have to configure anything else in revenuecat? or in google payments profile?

Thanks